# MkDocs site not getting deployed correctly to github pages

Tags: mkdocs

I am using [Deploy MkDocs](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-mkdocs) action to deploy my site to github pages. After pushing my changes to my master branch the action successfully runs.

However, when I visit my project page link then my site seems to be broken. Any pointers would be of great help.

My [repo](https://github.com/sapal6/nbdev.jl) structure is the following-->

[image]

The document contents are inside the "docs" directory.

When I tried to visit the site using my pages link, I can see something like this(I have checked my site locally and it renders properly on my local machine) -->

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. What did you do to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Add an `index.md` to the `src` folder e.g. When build this will produce needed `index.html` page. Also try to build with: `mkdocs build --clean`.

Comment: Hmmm.. still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe your problem is something else. This works as you can see on our site: https://czech-radio.github.io/organization/. Be sure you don!t use the Jekyll on GH pages.